# Deleting 5 minute old files every minute?

Tags: cron

I have a directory that gets filled with images from a web service and the images only need to exist on my server for 5 minutes after they've been placed. I tried using `tmpreaper` but I couldn't get it to work. I did the following command:

`sudo crontab -e`

```
* * * * * tmpreaper 5m /my_image/dir
```

I checked that the `cron` was running by `pgrep cron` and I got a `PID`. However, the images are still in the directory. Running the command manually works perfectly fine, however it's not working through cron.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, cron doesn't like raw commands in their files. Make a simple bash script that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpreaper 5m /my_image/dir
```

Save the script somewhere solid, make it executable, and change your cron to `bash /path/to/script`.

I've had issues with permissions with cron as well. Make sure it is being run by the correct user you are expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * *  find /yourDir/ -type f -mmin +5  -exec rm -f {} +
```

Command will run after every min and delete your files present in a directory that is older than 5 min.
resource : https://crontab.guru/every-1-minute